# Pass remote XML file using classic ASP

Tags: xml, web-services, asp-classic, xml-parsing, parse-error

I am accessing a webService, need to pass the XML and insert into a database.  To build the code I browse the file, downloaded it, wrote the code to store the info.  Great all working very well with the file locally!

So I change the code to load a URL and I have issues.  When I ask the parseError Object (errorCode, reason and line) what is wrong I get this:

```
XML Passer Object - Error Code = System error: -2147012889. 
XML Passer Object - Error Reason = -2147012889
XML Passer Object - Error Line = 0
```

There is almost no info at all on this '-2147012889' error code.  After looking at the code and getting it pier reviewed.  Nothing looks like it an issue.  The weird thing is when I place this XML file on one of our servers and run the passer code via one of our URL's it runs fine.   Is this a realistic test?  Simply placing the XML file on our server Vs hitting the webService URL that has been provided to me (it is a weather provider here is Australia).

Here is a very cut down and sanitised version of the XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
    <data>
      <metadata>
        <sector>weather</sector>
        <title>WeatherProvider</title>
        <last_commit>2014-08-11 09:15:22 +1000 (Mon, 11 Aug 2014)</last_commit>
        <validity>
          <date>2014-08-12</date>
          <day_name>Tuesday</day_name>
        </validity>
      </metadata>
      <weather>
        <countries>
          <country code="AU" name="Australia" region="Oceania">
            <location type="APLOC" code="6700" name="Addington" state="VIC" postcode="3352">
              <conditions>
                <related_location type="SITE" code="89002" name="Ballarat Ap"  state="VIC">
                </related_location>
                <obs_time_local tz="EST">2014-08-12T18:00:00</obs_time_local>
                <temp_c units="&#176;C">6.2</temp_c>
                <dp_c units="&#176;C">5.9</dp_c>
              </conditions>
            </location>
          </country>
        </countries>
      </weather>
    </data>
```

and here is a very cut down version of the VBScript:

```
<% 
Dim objXML, URL
URL = "http://theURL.com/theXMLFileName.xml"
Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
'Set objxml = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
'Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.async =  False
objXML.Load URL
Response.Write "XML Passer Object - Error Code = " & objXML.parseError.reason & "<BR>"
Response.Write "XML Passer Object - Error Reason = " & objXML.parseError.errorCode & "<BR>"
Response.Write "XML Passer Object - Error Line = " & objXML.parseError.line & "<BR><br>"
Response.Write "ASP Error Object Err.Des = " & Err.Description & "<br><br>"
dim last_commit
set last_commit     = objxml.getElementsByTagName("data/metadata/last_commit")
response.write "The expected last_commit value = " & last_commit.item(0).Text & "<br>"
%>
```

Here is the the output when i browse to the file either locally or when I place it as an XML file on one of our servers and browse to it via the above code:

```
XML Passer Object - Error Code = 
XML Passer Object - Error Reason = 0
XML Passer Object - Error Line = 0

ASP Error Object Err.Des = 

The expected last_commit value = 2014-08-11 09:15:22 +1000 (Mon, 11 Aug 2014)
```

and here is the problematic output when browsing to the 3rd party's webService URL (note line 21 is the very last line of code which writes 'last_commit.item(0).Text'):

```
XML Passer Object - Error Code = System error: -2147012889. 
XML Passer Object - Error Reason = -2147012889
XML Passer Object - Error Line = 0

ASP Error Object Err.Des = 

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: '[object]'

/bl/mattTest/XMLToASPRemoteBodyFullCode.asp, line 21
```

Am very stuck on this one.  Never seen anything like it.  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your code seems fine. It looks like the XML is being retrieved from your own server but not from theirs.  You could use `Response.Write objXML.text` to determine out wxactly what is in your object.  Also, out of the three options `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0` is the most recent version of MSXML so I'd go with that one unless you have a really old IIS version

Comment: the error code -2147012889 (corresponds to 80072ee7 in hexadecimal) means `The server name or address could not be resolved` often. first, you should make sure that your server resolves domain names.

Comment: After being on this ALL day its a proxy server issue.  Thank you John you are correct, no issues in the code.  Thank you also to @Kul-Tigin for the translation.  I went no where with this code, how did you translate this?

Comment: mmmm what should I do with the status of this post.  @Kul-Tigin has given what is best described as the solution.  I cant accept a sub-comment can I?

Comment: Is there any way EG additional parameters I can pass into the .Load  (or where ever suitable) to make sure the request can be routed correctly?  Perhaps pass in the Proxy IP and some credentials.  Or must I contact the Network guys ask for a special rule. Any advice would be great

Comment: I've run into this one.  There was a MS security patch that prevented ASP pages from loading external content.  Sorry I can't remember the details of the fix, but there was a Server setting to allow it again.